# Extension of IIdentity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, extension-methods, membership-provider, iidentity

I'm trying to use the exention method for IIdentity

Here is my class:

```
public static class MyIdentity 
{
    public static string FullName(this IIdentity identity)
    {
        return "John Doe";
    }
}
```

and I'm trying to use it on my view like this:

```
@Context.User.Identity.FullName()
```

but I get the following error:

> 'System.Security.Principal.IIdentity' does not contain a definition for 'FullName' and no extension method 'FullName' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Security.Principal.IIdentity' could be found

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you've brought the namespace in which this extension method is defined into scope in your view:

```
@using NameSpaceInWhichTheMyIdentityStaticClassIsDefined
@User.Identity.FullName()
```

or if you want to use it in many views to avoid adding this namespace in each view you could also add it to the `<namespaces>` section of `~/views/web.config` (Not to be confused with `~/web.config`):

```
<add namespace="NameSpaceInWhichTheMyIdentityStaticClassIsDefined" />
```